# Ways to allow users to change the color scheme of their account page

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design

Okay that title may not have been too clear, I am building a site for a client that will allow his clients to sell his merchandise. We will call his clients dealers. The dealers want to be able to change the logo and color scheme of the site to match their site. I do not want to go to every single div and table etc. and create a field in the database for it but at the same time I can't let them have full control over the CSS and potentially demolish what their site looks like. 
What is the best way to handle this and why?

Comment: If they're competent enough to handle CSS, why not let them?  Also, the design of the site matters.  Do you have one or two tones at different gradients?  You don't necessarily need to enable a clown-suit web site, just pick a couple of colors.  If they really do need more flexibility, CSS access makes sense, since it's hard to abstract something complex like that.

Comment: Use flag classes on the `body` or `html` class, e.g., `<html class="theme-blue">`. And then structure your CSS so that you can override colors and fonts, etc., by manipulating this with a COOKIE value you default to the one the client wants defaulted.

Comment: This is what I was talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ApSk3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the options given here and thinking hard about this I have decided that the truly best option for my situation is in fact limiting the items that people are able to change the color of and just store the options in the database. It is more work to begin with but saves on issues in the future

Answer (score 1):

You can use SASS, http://sass-lang.com/, to achieve this.

custom.scss:  - This is what you give to the clients to customize as they want to

```
/* COLORS */
$backgroundColor: #bada55;
$h1color: #red;
$navigationBackground: #yellow;
$navigationText: #black;
$navigationHover: #red;
$navigationFont: Tahoma;
...etc..

/* WIDGETS */
$arcticleBorderRadius: 5px;
...etc...

/* OTHER CATEGORIES */
```

In your app.scss import the custom.scss:

```
@import "custom.scss";

/* YOUR "PRIVATE" CSS RULES /*
body {
  background-color: $backgroundColor;
}

aside#nav {
   background-color: $navigationBackground;
   color: navigationText;

   > ul > li:hover {
        background-color: $navigationHover;
   }
}

/* etc, etc */
```

You can also use functions to lighten, darken, invert the base colors the customer can overide in custom.scss.

The "workflow" can be:

1. Customer overrides what they want, and what is available in custom.scss.
2. You get the custom.scss from the client, compiles a new css, e.g. acme-app.css.
3. The client calls the site with a request attribute "acme", or a path-variable http://www.myawesomesite.com/acme, in the url that identifies which generated css to load.